# Programmable USB Switch?

Tags: usb, kvm-switch

Is anyone aware of a USB Switch that is programmable or controlled via the PC?

I am writing a test application that requires the device (a mobile phone) to be plugged in via USB to a PC for initialization and then plugged in to a wall charger for a particular test.

Ideally I'd be able to have the phone plugged into the switch and then have two outputs from the switch - one to the PC and one to the wall charger. And then be able to set which connection to use from the PC.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I hate to say it, but this would be a trivial device for you to create yourself if you were willing to hack up a few USB cables.  All you need is a four-pole double throw switch.  Hook up all of your inputs and outputs, and bam, insta-USB switch.  And it won't cost more then a dollar if you already have the cables!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now - you want to use the switch *from* the PC.  In that case, you could use a microcontroller (control it via USB or serial) to switch between the two with a bunch of relays.

Comment: Right... That's similar to what I'm currently doing (switching using a PXI switch module)... But I was hoping to find a COTS solution.

Comment: Get an Arduino and some relays :)

Answer (score 4):

This product offering from Acroname looks like it might fit your needs. Programmable through C++ and Python API interface and designed for test automation and regression.

http://acroname.com/products/s77-usbhub-2x4-0

Answer (score 2):

http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/powerswitch.html

simple and cheap, will have to change it to operate relays instead of just powering lights.

I haven't build the powerswitch example, but have used vusb for both serial and keyboard projects. works with really cheap hardware.